# No applicable method for 'mae' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric') when mapping using map2_dbl?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, tibble

I am trying to calculate the **MAE** for a model I created and I receiving the following error:

```
x no applicable method for 'mae' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')
```

My mapping looks as such using **map2_dbl**:

```
cv_eval_rf <- cv_model_rf %>% 
  mutate(validate_mae = map2_dbl(validate_actual, validate_predicted, ~mae(actual = .x, predicted = .y)))
```

I am confused because when I examine the class of **validate_actual** & **validate_predicted** I get the following:
[image]

My **tibble** looks as such:
[image]

I am attempting to create another column named **validate_mae** as you see above in my calculation. Quite simply all I want to do is calculate the MAE for each tibble and attach it to this object so I can evaluate the best performing training/validation data.

Comment: Which package is `mae()` from?

Comment: Metrics I believe

Comment: [Please don't paste images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/13860)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many different packages implement a function called `mae`. You're using an `mae` function from the wrong package.

Your code should work if you use `Metrics::mae`.

```
cv_eval_rf <- cv_model_rf %>% 
  mutate(validate_mae = map2_dbl(validate_actual, validate_predicted, ~Metrics::mae(actual = .x, predicted = .y)))
```

`yardstick::mae` should also work with slightly different syntax

```
cv_eval_rf <- cv_model_rf %>% 
  yarstick::mae(validate_actual, validate_predicted)
```

Comment: That did it Metrics::mae! Thank you so much !!!! I cannot thank you enough